# How can I add citation to the hierarchy diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please can someone show me how to add citation (by using `\cite{thesis1}` which produces `[3]` and so on) and big curly braces like the following:

[image]

The code that I'm working on:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}


    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, 
    text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block2} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block3} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block4} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!40, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block5} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!50, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{block6} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!60, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2cm,
    minimum height=4em]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (collect) {Collecting EEG Data};
    \node [block2, below of=collect, node distance=2cm] (determine) {Determine Fast Fourier Transform of Primary Data for the Signals};
    \node [block3, below of=determine, node distance=2cm] (flat) {Flattening the EEG Data};
    \node [block4, below of=flat, node distance=2cm] (decide) {EEG data viewed as a set of upper triangular matrices};
    \node [block5, below of=decide, node distance=2cm] (semigroup) {Semigroup of upper triangular matrices for EEG data ($+$)};
    \node [block6, below of=semigroup, node distance=2cm] (KR) {Krohn-Rhodes Decomposition of semigroup of EEG signals};
    \node [block, below of=KR, node distance=2.5cm] (newsemigroup) {New Semigroups of EEG signals (*)};
    \node [block, left of=newsemigroup, node distance=4cm] (affine) {Semigroup of Affine Scalling};
    \node [block, right of=newsemigroup, node distance=4cm] (diagonal) {Semigroup of Diagonal Matrices};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (collect) -- (determine);
    \path [line] (determine) -- (flat);
    \path [line] (flat) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- (semigroup);
    \path [line] (semigroup) -- (KR);
    \path [line] (KR) -- (newsemigroup);
    \path [line] (KR) -|  (affine);
    \path [line] (KR) -|  (diagonal);
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

One more thing, how can I create other colour other than standard colour like blue and red. Anyone's help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use `\tikzset`. `\tikzstyle` is depreciated.

You can get the curly braces by `decorations.pathreplacing`. However, it is a bit tricky to get the starting and the ending points of the braces, as well as adding a label at `midway`.

Here I simply add `[3]`, `[49]`, etc. You should change to suitable citation commands in your real document.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\tikzset{
    decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
        text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt},
    block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    block2/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
        text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    block3/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    block4/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!40, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    block5/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!50, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    block6/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!60, 
    text width=12em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style = {draw, -latex'},
    cloud/.style = {draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2cm,
    minimum height=4em}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (collect) {Collecting EEG Data};
    \node [block2, below of=collect, node distance=2cm] (determine) {Determine Fast Fourier Transform of Primary Data for the Signals};
    \node [block3, below of=determine, node distance=2cm] (flat) {Flattening the EEG Data};
    \node [block4, below of=flat, node distance=2cm] (decide) {EEG data viewed as a set of upper triangular matrices};
    \node [block5, below of=decide, node distance=2cm] (semigroup) {Semigroup of upper triangular matrices for EEG data ($+$)};
    \node [block6, below of=semigroup, node distance=2cm] (KR) {Krohn-Rhodes Decomposition of semigroup of EEG signals};
    \node [block, below of=KR, node distance=2.5cm] (newsemigroup) {New Semigroups of EEG signals (*)};
    \node [block, left of=newsemigroup, node distance=4cm] (affine) {Semigroup of Affine Scalling};
    \node [block, right of=newsemigroup, node distance=4cm] (diagonal) {Semigroup of Diagonal Matrices};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (collect) -- (determine);
    \path [line] (determine) -- (flat);
    \path [line] (flat) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -- (semigroup);
    \path [line] (semigroup) -- (KR);
    \path [line] (KR) -- (newsemigroup);
    \path [line] (KR) -|  (affine);
    \path [line] (KR) -|  (diagonal);
    \draw [
        thick,decorate,
        decoration={
            brace,
            amplitude=10pt,
            raise=5pt}
    ] ($(collect.north)+(5.5,0)$) -- ($(flat.south)+(5.5,0)$) node [midway,right=3ex] {[3]};
    \coordinate (x) at ($(newsemigroup.south)+(5.5,0)$);
    \draw [
        thick,decorate,
        decoration={
            brace,
            amplitude=10pt,
            raise=5pt}
    ] ($(decide.north)+(5.5,0)$) -- (x |- diagonal.south east) node [midway,right=3ex] {[49]};
    \draw [
        thick,decorate,
        decoration={
            brace,
            amplitude=10pt,
            raise=5pt,
            mirror}
    ] ($(KR.north)+(-5.5,0)$) -- ($(newsemigroup.south)+(-5.5,0)$) node [midway,left=3ex] {[50]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]